# SAPUI5 OData Model change a property at run time

Tags: model, odata, sapui5

I have a Fiori List Report with Grid Table and want to set the status of a property so as to highlight the row. How do I retrieve the OData Model in extension controller and iterate over it to set the *property.status - "Error/ Warning"* and set back the model/ refresh.

I am able to get the model in controller as `this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/")`

How can I loop over it to read each of the record and set status of a property based on some condition.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you do not loop over them. you bind a control the the status property.

Comment: the model is already bound to Grid Table

Comment: then you do not need to loop over to to update the status. condition can be provided in a formatter.

Comment: thank you, do u have any references/ links/ code snippets

Comment: provide in the answer

Answer (score 0):

a sample to format label controller (simulating model changes with setInterval) - http://jsbin.com/pacexa/edit?html,js,output

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Text</title>
  <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" type="text/javascript" src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex">
  </script>

  <!-- XML-based view definition -->
  <script id="oView" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View height="100%" controllerName="myView.Template" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" class="viewPadding">
      <Label text="{path:'/status', formatter: 'myFormatter.formatText'
}" />
    </mvc:View>
  </script>
  <script>
    //Formatter Definition
    var myFormatter = {
      formatText: function(status) {
        if (status === "OK") {
          return "Good";
        }
        return "Bad";
      }
    };
    // Controller definition
    sap.ui.define([
      'jquery.sap.global',
      'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
      'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'
    ], function(jQuery, Controller, JSONModel) {
      "use strict";

      var cController = Controller.extend("myView.Template", {
        onInit: function(oEvent) {
          var oModel = new JSONModel({
            status: "OK",
          });
          var oView = this.getView();
          oView.setModel(oModel);

          setInterval(function() {
            oModel.setProperty("/status", oModel.getProperty("/status") === "OK" ? "ERR" : "OK");
          }, 1000);
        }
      });

      return cController;
    });

    // Instantiate the View and display
    var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
      viewContent: jQuery('#oView').html()
    });
    oView.placeAt('content');
  </script>
    </head>

<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the code snippet. However, for a List Report template it was tricky. Found another way of adding an additional column and setting it a formatter which worked.

Thanks...